# Processing: Soundfile not found

Tags: audio, processing, audio-player

I have a bit of code that is supposed to play a music file when run.

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile soundtrack;

void setup(){

    soundtrack = new SoundFile(this, "space_music.wav");

    //soundtrack.play();

}

void draw(){}
```

When I run the code, the rest works fine except for the soundtrack initialization. An error message pops up that says

```
Error: Soundfile doesn't exist. Pleae check path
```

When I uncomment the soundtrack.play(), the code just straight up refuses to run. This also happens when the soundtrack.play() is in the draw loop. I double checked to make sure the file names match. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, the error message says it all. It can't find that file. Are you absolutely sure that's the name of the file? Is it in the `data` directory of your sketch? What exactly do you mean by "straight up refuses to run"?

Comment: I made sure the file name was correct. Where would the data directory be? I don't see one for any of my sketches. Also, what I mean is that the program doesn't run.

Comment: If you don't have a data directory, how did you add the sound file to your sketch? Where exactly is it located?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the sound library first.

Sketch > import library... >  search for sound > install sound library

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to create a dir(folder) named "data" in the same dir(folder) of your .pde file

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, this exactly fixed my problem

Comment: I agree. The answer isn't wrong - it's just not stylistically good. I've upvoted and edited it to be clearer. Please upvote / set as correct answer if you agree.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you are using the latest software and Sound Library from processing.

Adding sound library from processing using Sketch > Import Library... > Sound is the best to make sure all is correct and library is installed properly.

Then you must specify the full path or the directory or location of the sound file. You can't just add "space_music.wav". You have to completely put the exact location of that file.

example:
Your processing .pde file is on

C:\My Documents\Processing\project_1\project.pde

and your sound file is on

C:\My Documents\Processing\project_1\soundfile.mp3

Then you have to write

`soundtrack = new SoundFile(this, "C:\My Documents\Processing\project_1\soundfile.mp3");`